# Spring Data repository Auto injection failing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to upgrade my project to Spring 5.0.6 and Spring Data 2.0.6 and we are using WebSphere managed JPA 2.1

Getting below exception while creating the Spring context:

> [5/29/18 6:30:41:929 CDT] 00000052 SystemOut     O 06:30:41.876 [Default : 5] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mmm.arc.dao.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>
> ...

### service class:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED )

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {


    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
}
```

### repository class:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor< User >,UserRepositoryCustom{

}

public class UserRepositoryImpl implements  UserRepositoryCustom{

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
-----------methods
}
```

in schema i have not mentioned any spring version

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="repo class package" /><bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistance unit name"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

we have separate  persistence.xml file  to map all entities which are completely annotation based

Comment: Show the relevant code where you `@Autowire` the repository, please.

Comment: many things come into play here, your type of config (annotations or XML), the packages you are telling spring to scan, the way you declared your bean, etc.  Please post the relevant code and we'll point you in the right direction.  I've had this error for a variety of reasons throughout the development of my app and still continue to do so once in a while when i break something :)

Comment: @martin ,@Nikolas Thanks for your response i have updated the code related to basic config . all configurations are working in spring 3.2 version

Comment: sorry i am mostly familiar with the newer annotation style config for spring (which you should totally check out btw).  These questions are usually answered very quickly so someone should get you going in no time at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your bean `UserRepositoryImpl` doesn't implement `interface UserRepository`, which is the type that `UserServiceImpl` is using. Thus, I think there actually is no `UserRepository` instance created anywhere.

Perhaps you intended for `UserRepositoryImpl` to `implement UserRespository` instead of `UserRepositoryCustom`?

Comment: thanks for your response. if we implements UserRepository the UserRepositoryImpl will force us to implement the default methods in JpaRepository. if we have to implement JpaRepository methods then no use of using spring-data features.

Comment: Nonetheless, you can't leave it the way it is, the classes simply don't match the requirements. You could change your `userRepository` to type `UserRepositoryCustom` instead, but Java cannot assign a `UserRepositoryCustom` object to a `UserRepository` variable. That's why Spring can't either. A `UserRespository` is a also a `UserRepositoryCustom` (in addition to the two Jpa interfaces), but a `UserRepositoryCustom` is not a `UserRepository` (because it doesn't implement the two Jpa interfaces).